# How do I nest components with vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm new to vue and trying to port an old-school boostrap app to a BS5 + vue3 model.  I'm trying to recreate this: https://www.screencast.com/t/ZfnE60z4cR8 based on a json object pulled from an api.  At the moment it's 4 nested arrays of objects (arrays to retain sorting) but I can change to any structure I need to if this isn't optimal.  In a nutshell, facilities contain spaces contain devices contain data points (temp, humidity, etc).  There are alarms and other conditions but at the moment I'm just trying to figure out how to render the basic structure.  I have a hunch that components make the most sense and I got the facilities to render, but how do I render spaces inside those containers, then devices and each of their relevant datapoints (which I assume would be the same component passed a name, value and unit - like %rH, degrees F, etc.)

```
    <div id="db">
        <facility-block v-for="facility in facilities" :name="facility.name">
            <space-block v-for="space in facilities.spaces" :name="space.name">
                
            </space-block>
        </facility-block>
    </div>
```

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/daemach/pen/abNQdoq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just targeting the wrong variable. Instead of `facilities.spaces` you likely are looking for `facility.spaces`

```html
<div id="db">
    <facility-block v-for="facility in facilities" :name="facility.name">
        <space-block v-for="space in facility.spaces" :name="space.name">
        </space-block>
    </facility-block>
</div>
```